# Delete part of canvas and image altogether

Tags: windows, image, photoshop, gimp, paint.net

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this.

I have a picture [image]

and I want to delete the highlited part [image]

So the final image looks like [image]

Basically, what I usually do is delete the highlited part, align the bottom part with the top one and crop the canvas, but I was wondering if there is a program that lets you do everything in one step (deleting the section of the canvas and the image altogether)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paint.NET:

Select that area with the Rectangle Select tool, then press delete.

Select the bottom part of the image, switch to the Move Selected Pixels tool, and hold the up arrow key until it's in place. (ctrl + up arrow = 10 pixels at a time)

Now you need to crop it. Switch to the Magic Wand tool, set the Tolerance to zero, click in the newly transparent area at the bottom, then invert the selection (Edit -> Invert Selection), then crop (Image -> Crop to Selection).